# Brother QL 720NW Android and iPhone Printing

Tags: android, iphone

I want to print label from my Android and iPhone application.
Printer is Brother QL 720NW
I had tried iprintsdk.com but I am not sure how I can use it.
And it seems it is not free.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to check whether your printer is airprint compatible, if so, you wont need an app:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356

if its not, try downloading a free printing app to start with from the App store like printdirect for iOS or a paid for app Print for both android and ios

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eurosmartz.app.print&feature=search_result